# Invariant Violation : Usage Issue for npm Library

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, import, babeljs

I am trying to use the react-google-login found in npm [site](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-google-login), but i am running in to some issues . The Error is

```
bundle.js:3104 Warning: React.createElement: type should not be null, undefined, boolean, or number. It should be a string (for DOM elements) or a ReactClass (for composite components). Check the render method ofLogin.
```

and

```
bundle.js:3104 Warning: React.createElement: type should not be null, undefined, boolean, or number. It should be a string (for DOM elements) or a ReactClass (for composite components). Check the render method ofLogin
```

This may be because because of the usage issue . I may not have imported properly too . Any help is very much appreciated.

```
var React = require('react')
var GoogleLogin = require('react-google-login')
var Login = React.createClass({
    responseGoogle(e){
        console.log("response",e)
    },
    render:function(){
        return <div>
          <GoogleLogin
            clientId="xxxxxxxxxxx-yyyyyyyyyy.apps.googleusercontent.com"
            buttonText="Login"
            callback={this.responseGoogle} />
        </div>
    },
});
module.exports = Login;
```

~

This is most probably calling an unwanted function or class. I have been using the require and i am not familiar with import. Any suggestions or notes on proper way of figuring out correct syntaxes on the future is also highlh appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried:

```
var GoogleLogin = require('react-google-login').default
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a line to export your component.

```
export default Login;
```

Comment: Sorry but this did not work . May work if i use import maybe ?

Comment: It would definitely work with import and it should work with this.. check this link out once https://toddmotto.com/react-create-class-versus-component/

Comment: Thanks a lot for the link!